# Where does Colloquy on the Mac store its channel list?

Tags: macos, mac, irc, colloquy

I use Colloquy as my IRC client - but the GUI sometimes doesn't store my prefs as to what channels I auto join etc - is there a plist file somewhere that I can edit to make the changes I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colloquy stores it's details in it's preference file found in `~/Library/Preferences/info.colloquy.plist`.

Specifically you're looking for the details in `MVChatBookmarks`. If you make one you can copy and paste the format for your other servers you wish to set up.

Answer (score 1):

The application support directory mentioned Jonik has some preferences, but I think what you're looking for is in `~/Library/Preferences/info.colloquy.plist`